# phrases extraction with R

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining

I am trying to extract sentiment polarity for film review, so for this from a tagged text (using treetagger) I would like to extract all the bi-grams which tags are (ADV - VER:pper) or (VER:pres - ADJ). For example in the example below the list of extracted phrases is : bien suivi, est efficace.

Can you give some help please?

thank you in advance

```
Database <- read.table("exp.txt", header = FALSE)
Database



          V1       V2         V3

1     Toujours      ADV   toujours
2         bien      ADV       bien
3        suivi VER:pper     suivre
4          par      PRP        par
5          mon  DET:POS        mon
6   conseiller      NOM conseiller
7          Bon      NAM  <unknown>
8      accueil      NOM    accueil
9            ,      PUN          ,
10          ma  DET:POS        mon
11 conseillère      NOM conseiller
12         est VER:pres       être
13    efficace      ADJ   efficace
14          et      KON         et
15           à      PRP          à
16          l'  DET:ART         le
17      écoute      NOM     écoute
18           .
```

Comment: I think you have something like the following in mind. `df <- data.frame(a=rep(c("a","b","c"),3),b=1:9)`, `df[df$a %in% c("b","c"),]`. I suggest you take some time to learn R.

Comment: @DJJ Ok thank you , Sure I'll do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dplyr` to accomplish what you need:

```
library(dplyr)

Database %>% 
    mutate(NV1 = lead(V1), NV2 = lead(V2)) %>% 
    filter((V2 == 'ADV' & NV2 == 'VER:pper') | (V2 == 'VER:pres' & NV2 == 'ADJ')) %>%
    transmute(result = paste(V1, NV1))

#       result
#   bien suivi
# est efficace
```

Note that this is not very scalable, as you have to type any condition you need, but is something to start and may suits your need

Comment: is it possible to save the result in a variable?

Comment: sure, just add `-> result` at the end